# Efficient parsing of URL arguments to a dictionary

Tags: javascript

I have a URL argument `red=3&red=5&blue=xyz&green=true` that I need to parse into a dictionary `({red:[3,5], blue:['xyz'], green:[true]})`. Grateful for pointers towards any more elegant solution to my current approach:

```
> var args = ('red=3&red=5&blue=xyz&green=true').split('&');

> d = {};

> for(var i=0; i<args.length; i++){
  var a = args[i].split('=');
  var key = a[0];
  if(d[key] == undefined){
  d[key] = [ a[1] ];
  } else { d[key].push( a[1] ); }
}

> d
{…}
blue: Array [ "xyz" ]
green: Array [ "true" ]
red: Array [ "3", "5" ]
__proto__: Object { … }
```

Comment: Thanks, anonymous downvoter!

Comment: I'd suggest "d.hasOwnProperty( key )" instead of testing for undefined.

Comment: useful tip tx @flowtron

Comment: You can try `d[key] = d[key] || []; d[key].push(...)`. If you are open to ES6, then may be `const [key, value] = args[i].split('=')`. Also, if you are getting this url from browser, you may want to use `encodeUri` as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the suggestions, all. Based on suggestion by @Rajesh I think this is probably as good as it gets:

```
var args = ('red=3&red=5&blue=xyz&green=true').split('&');
d = {};
for(var i=0; i<args.length; i++){
  var a = args[i].split('=');
  d[a[0]] = d[a[0]] || []
  d[a[0]].push(a[1])
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try `reduce` for this. Please see below solution.

```js
var qr = 'red=3&red=5&blue=xyz&green=true';
var obj = decodeURI(qr).split('&').reduce(function(acc, item) {
  var key = item.split('=')[0];
  var val = item.split('=')[1];
  if (acc[key] && Array.isArray(acc[key])) {
    acc[key].push(val);
  } else if (acc[key] && !Array.isArray(acc[key])) {
    acc[key] = [acc[key]].concat([val])
  } else {
    acc[key] = val;
  }
  return acc;
}, {});
console.log(obj);
```

If you want to convert `numbers` and `booleans`, then you can add additional condition like below. Not sure, whether conversion is best solution or not though.

```js
var qr = 'red=3&red=5&blue=xyz&green=true';
var obj = decodeURI(qr).split('&').reduce(function(acc, item) {
  var key = item.split('=')[0];
  var val = item.split('=')[1];
  if (val == 'true' || val === 'false' || !isNaN(val)) {
    val = eval(val);
  }
  if (acc[key] && Array.isArray(acc[key])) {
    acc[key].push(val);
  } else if (acc[key] && !Array.isArray(acc[key])) {
    acc[key] = [acc[key]].concat([val])
  } else {
    acc[key] = val;
  }
  return acc;
}, {});
console.log(obj);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try below solution if you need :

```
var d = {};
var args = 'red=3&red=5&blue=xyz&green=true';
args.split('&').map((a, b) => {
    d[a.split('=')[0]] = (typeof d[a.split('=')[0]] === 'undefined')?[]:d[a.split('=')[0]];
    switch(true){
        case a.split('=')[1].toLowerCase() == 'true' || a.split('=')[1].toLowerCase() == 'false':
        case String(Number(a.split('=')[1]))!= 'NaN':
          d[a.split('=')[0]].push(eval(a.split('=')[1]));
        break;
        default:
          d[a.split('=')[0]].push(a.split('=')[1]);
     }
     });
    console.log(d);
```